# Firma para email en html no se copia correctamente

Tags: html, email, gmail, outlook

Tengo una firma en html para ponerla al final de todos mis emails pero no consigo copiarla correctamente y no sé si puede ser debido a algún error en el código.

La firma es esta:

HTML:

```html
<table style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 13px;" border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 11px;" colspan="4"><br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="25">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="middle" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="240"><strong>Fausto S&aacute;nchez Hoya</strong><br />Digital Business Consultant<br /><a style="color: #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:Mail" target="_blank" rel="noopener">EjemploMail</a><br />Ejemplo tlf <br /><br /> <a style="color: #95bc45; padding-top: 3px; border-top: 1px solid #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.lm-consulting.es/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> www.lm-consulting.es</a> <a style="color: #95bc45; padding-top: 3px; border-top: 0px solid #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.whystrategic.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> www.whystrategic.com</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#4D4442" width="120" height="120"><img src="https://lm-consulting.es/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/faviconWeb.png" alt="WHY" width="95" /></td>
<td bgcolor="#4D4442" width="120" height="120" href="http://www.whystrategic.com/"><img src="http://whystrategic.com/rs/logo_why_firma.png" alt="WHY" width="60" /></td>
<td style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="15">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="height: 12px;" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

A la hora de introducir la firma en el Outlook para empresas (el cual no deja incluir código html sino que tengo que copiar y pegar como si fuera texto la firma html) me sale como sin formato.

La firma si la abres con cualquier editor de código o con cualquier navegador se ve bien. He probado a copiar y a pegar otras firmas en el Outlook y funcionan correctamente y he probado a pegar la firma en gmail pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: El HTML y los estilos que interpretan y aceptan los editores de email no son tan extensos ni complejos como un navegador cualquiera. Si la firma en su estado actual no puede copiarse al abrirla en un navegador y copiar/pegar, el camino es revisar la documentación y modificarla. Por ejemplo, tu documento HTML está incompleto; no tiene tags `<html>`...

Comment: esto te puede ayudar https://www.gacelaweb.com/configurar-firmas-html-outlook/

Comment: @FaustoSánchezHoya la edición que has realizado daña la publicación porque quitas una parte importante (cómo quieres que se vea). La pregunta deja de tener sentido si lo quitas. He revertido la edición a la original.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro importa que el OP pueda estar preocupado porque reciba spam o algo así? No sé, sólo pregunto

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro he cambiado de datos y ahora tanto el email como el teléfono no me pertenecen por lo que veo lógico quitarlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu firma debe ser un documento HTML correcto y completo.

Prueba completándola para ver si logras que tome todos los estilos que buscas. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo que podría funcionar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mi Firma</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 13px;" border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 11px;" colspan="4">
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="25">&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="240">
                <strong>Fausto S&aacute;nchez Hoya</strong>
                <br/>Digital Business Consultant<br/>
                <a style="color: #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:fausto.sh@whystrategic.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">fausto.sh@whystrategic.com</a>
                <br/>630581578 <br/>
                <br/>
                <a style="color: #95bc45; padding-top: 3px; border-top: 1px solid #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.lm-consulting.es/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> www.lm-consulting.es</a>
                <a style="color: #95bc45; padding-top: 3px; border-top: 0px solid #95bc45; text-decoration: none;" href="http://www.whystrategic.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> www.whystrategic.com</a>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#4D4442" width="120" height="120">
                <img src="https://lm-consulting.es/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/faviconWeb.png" alt="WHY" width="95"/>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#4D4442" width="120" height="120" href="http://www.whystrategic.com/">
                <img src="http://whystrategic.com/rs/logo_why_firma.png" alt="WHY" width="60"/>
            </td>
            <td style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;" bgcolor="#4D4442" width="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 12px;" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

La probé en Outlook y funciona :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, esto me ha servido :D